# Validating IP address and ip address ranges delimited by semicolon

Tags: php, regex

Here's the problem, I allow users to input an IP whitelist or list of IPs or IP ranges separated by semicolon.

So they can put

```
74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222 - 80.788.888.111; 72.203.44.209
74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209
74.122.31.233 - 76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209
74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209
74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222;72.203.44.209
```

They can choose to use spaces or not to use spaces between ranges and before/after semicolons.

So they can either put IP addresses separated by semicolon or IP address ranges separated by semicolons or IP addresses and IP ranges separated by semi colons.

I am new to regular expresses. Does anyone know the right way to validate if they input the IP whitelist correctly to adhere to the rules above?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be difficult using regex alone, since ranges mean there is number comparison as well, and either you'll get a long complicated working regex if it exists, or use regex only to check the format, and other functions to check the validity of the IP ranges.

Comment: You could simply replace all characters that are not numbers or your preferable separator with the empty string so the format will always be the same, then it's easy to check the length and add custom separators.

Comment: I would be tempted to make a 3 step process. 1. Split your input text using the ";" 2. split the results again by "-". 3. After this you are left with a list of IP addresses. These you can check easily using RegEx or maybe something in PHP. Any step fails you have invalid input. Remember to strip of the spaces also.

Comment: I agree with @GeorgeBrighton's answer that regex is unnecessary here. However just for your reference check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: You also need to take into account private vs public IP4 address ranges. Also it is not very useful to use IP addresses at all as they can be shared by the router(s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not convinced regular expressions are necessary or even helpful in this case, especially as PHP has [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
function isValid($ranges) {

    // remove all spaces
    $ranges = str_replace(' ', '', $ranges);

    // iterate over individual ranges and IP addresses
    foreach(explode(';', $ranges) as $range) {

        // single address
        if(strpos($range, '-') === false) {
            if(!filter_var($range, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // range
        else {
            $addresses = explode('-', $range, 3);

            if(count($addresses) != 2) {
                return false;
            }

            if(!filter_var($addresses[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) || !filter_var($addresses[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

$tests = array(
    '74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222 - 80.788.888.111; 72.203.44.209',
    '74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209',
    '74.122.31.233 - 76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209',
    '74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209',
    '74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222;72.203.44.209');

foreach($tests as $test) {
    echo $test;
    echo isValid($test) ? ' is valid' : ' is invalid';
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222 - 80.788.888.111; 72.203.44.209 is invalid // 80.788.888.111 is an invalid IP address
74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209 is valid
74.122.31.233 - 76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209 is valid
74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209 is valid
74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222;72.203.44.209 is valid
```

Answer (score 2):

Explode them by `;`, and then `trim` the array values to remove the spaces. That way, you can make sure both the spaced-version and non-spaced versions of the user input is treated equally.

```
$parts = explode(';', $text);
$parts = array_map('trim', $parts);
//or $parts = array_map('trim', explode(';', $text));
//check if IP is valid
```

For validating the IP, you don't need a regular expression. PHP already has a built-in function [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) which does exactly what you want.

```
$parts = array_map('trim', explode(';', $text));

foreach ($parts as $ip) {
    if(strpos($ip, '-')) {
        list($range1, $range2) = explode('-', $ip); 
        // validate IP range here
    }    
    elseif (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) ) {
        echo "$ip is valid<br/>";
    }
}
```

That should get you started.

Comment: remember he needs to support the ranges also using the "-"

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to cram everything into a single regular expression. I know you're thinking that, classic rookie mistake.

1. Remove the whitespace from the input: `$input = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $input);`
2. Split on semicolons: `$in_arr = explode(';', $input);`
3. Loop through the array and `if( preg_match('/-/', $in_arr[index]) )` then `explode('-', $in_arr[index]);` and then process it like a range
4. To validate IP addresses *don't use a regular expression*. Use `ip2long()`.

   - Every valid IP address is really a 32-bit integer, the 'dotted quad' notation just breaks that integer into four 8-bit chunks from 0-255.
   - If you feed an invalid address like `80.788.888.111` into `ip2long()` it will return false, no complicated regex needed.
   - Using `ip2long()` makes it *way* easier to compare IP addresses as well, `'123.123.123.3' > '123.123.123.10'` [string comparison, bad], but `ip2long('123.123.123.3') < ip2long('123.123.123.10')` [integer comparison, good]

Comment: I think point 1. is not correct way to go. If user inputs ip address which has space, like `123. 123.123.123`, this should be validated as invalid.

Comment: @Glavić I think glossing over that (minor) space issue is okay given the philosophy of [flexible inputs](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?989).

Comment: My answer also doesn't detect that - but I think it's a feature rather than a bug :) I do disagree with the use of ip2long() here though - it isn't intended to be a validation function, and so accepts IP addresses like 127.0.255.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton I'm assuming you mean 127.0.0.255, and are generally referring to private/reserved address spaces. So? There's nothing in OPs question stating that the IPs entered *must* be publicly routable. It's also a simple matter to implement checks from private IP spaces using `ip2long()`.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton: `ip2long('127.0.255.')` returns `false`, just like `filter_var` does. @Sammitch: `ip2long` doesn't support ipv6, but `filter_var` does, but yes, OP didn't say he needed ipv6 support ;)

Comment: Sorry - yes I got that wrong. I misinterpreted the documentation on the ip2long() page about it accepting non-complete IP addresses...

Comment: @Glavić if you need IPv6 support just change `ip2long()` for `inet_pton()` and then wrap you head around comparing binary strings. :P

Comment: OOH! `bin2hex(inet_pton('DEAD:BEEF::1'));` gives `deadbeef000000000000000000000001` and then I suppose string comparisons should still work.

Comment: `DEAD:BEEF` loool ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple function :

```
function validateInput($s) {
    foreach (explode(';', $s) as $v) {
        $v = array_map('trim', explode('-', $v));
        if (count($v) > 2) return false;
        $valid = true;
        foreach ($v as $ip) $valid = $valid && filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
        if (!$valid) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Use example :

```
$inputs = [
    '74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222 - 80.788.888.111; 72.203.44.209',
    '74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209',
    '74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222;72.203.44.209',
    '274.122.31.233-76.233.12.222',
    '74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222-77.233.12.222',
];

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    echo (validateInput($input) ? 'TRUE ' : 'FALSE') . " : $input\n";
}
```

Output :

```
FALSE : 74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222 - 80.788.888.111; 72.203.44.209
TRUE  : 74.122.31.233; 76.233.12.222; 72.203.44.209
TRUE  : 74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222;72.203.44.209
FALSE : 274.122.31.233-76.233.12.222
FALSE : 74.122.31.233-76.233.12.222-77.233.12.222
```